# What is the algorithm behind My News in SharePoint app bar?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, microsoft-graph, newsfeed, sharepoint-app-bar

Could you please tell me what is the algorithm behind My News in SharePoint app bar, which has been introduced recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personalized content (sites/**news**/files) in the SharePoint app bar is enabled by **Microsoft Graph**.

**Source**: [Introducing a SharePoint app bar that features global navigation](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/02/24/introducing-a-sharepoint-app-bar-that-features-global-navigation/)

---

**How news posts for the personalized feed are determined**

Using the power of Microsoft Graph, SharePoint blends news in your personalized feed from:

- People you work with
- Managers in the chain of people you work with, mapped against your own chain of management and connections
- Your top 20 followed sites
- Your frequently visited sites

**Note**: You may see news in your personalized feed from a site you've recently visited only once. Unless you frequent or follow this site, it will eventually cycle out of your feed as new news posts fill your feed.

**Source**: [Create and share news on your SharePoint sites](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-share-news-on-your-sharepoint-sites-495f8f1a-3bef-4045-b33a-55e5abe7aed7)

Comment: If a news post is targeted to a group and if a user who follows that site but not in that group, will that user see the news post in my news section in the app bar?

Comment: If user don't have permissions to see the news post, it will not be shown. Microsoft Graph respects the original permissions of SharePoint